# header value in regex expression for apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to read files from a folder that correspond to a regex like this

```
from("direct:queuealpha").process(new DateTagGenerator()).from("file:///folder1/folder2/?delete=false&include=.*(${headers.timetag}).*);
```

So DateTagGenerator sets a header with a value I want to use in the regex as input. I tried escaping  `{, $ and }` as well as using simple but I am obviously doing sth wrong.

How can I dynamically create a value for a header or the body, which can then be used for a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Camel 2.16 you can use the *Content Enricher* with dynamic endpoints ([doc][1]) and in particular the `pollEnrich` (as you are using a `file` endpont)

```
from("direct:queuealpha")
  .process(new DateTagGenerator())
  .pollEnrich.simple("file:/folder1/folder2/?delete=false&include=${headers.timetagExpr}")
  .process(…) // you can now process the message
  .to(…); // and send it onward
```

Comment: just saw a duplicate on SO...i'll leave the answer here anyway